# javascript instanceof operator, prototype chains - Object and Function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm trying to understand following code snippet:

```
> Object instanceof Function
true
> Function instanceof Object
true
```

Quite surprising, it works both ways.

The first line. `Object` is a constructor, since I can do `new Object()`, and all constructors are functions in JS. So the first is satisfied.

The second line. `Function` is function constructor. But functions are also first-class citizens in JS, so all functions are objects in JS.

As a result, whatever is an instance of `Object`, it's also instance of `Function` and the other way round also.

**Does that mean, that there is a cycle prototype inheritance in base types in JavaScript core**, between `Object` and `Function`? Is my understanding correct or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Why would instances of `Object` be instances of `Function`?

Comment: Key to understand this, is the word ***chain***, in *prototype chain*.

Comment: `(Object) instanceof Function` might be true, but `(new Object) instanceof Function` isn't - it does not follow from the first. In other words: `Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object)` and `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(new Object)` have nothing to do with each other

Comment: @melpomene `Object` and **an instance** of `Object` is not the same
@trincot that doesn't help me **much**... I know prototypal inheritance is a chain - but is there a cycle?
@Bergi still doesn't help me **much**...

Comment: Yes, exactly. So why are you saying "*whatever is an instance of `Object`, it's also instance of `Function`*" when you've only checked `Object instanceof Function`?